# why replace ocelot api gateway with rabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, ocelot

We are making a cloud native enterprise business application on dotnet core mvc platform. The dotnet core default api gateway between frontend application and backend microservices is Ocelot used in Async mode.

We have been suggested to use RabbitMQ message broker instead of Ocelot. The reasoning given for this shift is asynchronous request - response exchange between frontend and microservices. Here, we would like to declare that our application would have few hundred cshtml pages spanning over several frontend modules. We are expecting over thousand users concurrently using the application.

Our concern is that, is it the right suggestion or not. Our development team feels that we should continue using Ocelot api gateway for general request - response exchange between frontend and microservices and use RabbitMQ only for events which are going to trigger backgroup processing and respond after a delay when the job gets completed.

In case you guys feel that yes we can replace Ocelot, then our further concerns about reliable session based request and response. We should not have to programmaticaly corelate response to session requests. Here it may please be noted that with RabbitMQ we are testing with dotnet core MassTransit library. The Ocelot API Gateway is designed to handle session based request-response commnunication.

In RabbitMQ should we make reply queue for each request or should the client maintain a single reply queue for all requests. Should the reply queue be exclusive or durable.

Can single reply queue per client be able to serve to all request or will it be correct to make multiple receive endpoint based on application modules/cshtml pages to serve all our concurrent users with efficient way.

Thanking you all, we eagerly wait for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to implement RabbitMQ. You might need to change ocelot to rabbit mq.